# The named parameter 'title' isn't defined. problem in flutter

Tags: flutter

new BottomNavigationBarItem(
icon: new Icon(Icons.home, color: (_page == 0) ?Color.fromRGBO(79, 119,45,1) : Color.fromRGBO(236, 243,158,1)),
title: new Container(height: 0.0),

Answer (score 1):

It will be `label` as `title` is deprecated for that.

Follow this link : https://docs.flutter.dev/release/breaking-changes/bottom-navigation-title-to-label